# Get Updated Object when using ObjectDataSource and Repeater

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, .net-4.5

I have a data repeater that is binding to an ObjectDataSource on a page. I have the select working but I am having a problem with the Update. When I call a Save button what I want to do is call the function specified in the UpdateMethod and pass it in a parameter of the changed object of the repeater.  Problem is I can't figure out how to get the object back out of the repeater. I do not want to specify each individual field as an update parameter as that is really unwieldy and defeats the purpose of data binding. Any help on this would be great.

```
    <%@ Page Language="VB" %>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" ItemType="CompanyObject">
        <ItemTemplate>      
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" CssClass="clsLabel">Company:</asp:Label>  
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCompany" runat="server" Text='<%# BindItem.Company%>'></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:Repeater>
        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server"
        SelectMethod="GetData" TypeName="WebApplication1.CompanyObject"
        UpdateMethod="UpdateCompany" DataObjectTypeName="CompanyObject"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code behind that I want to call:

```
Public Function UpdateCompany(ByVal company As tblCompany)
'Save the Value here except that company is always null
End Function

Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    ObjectDataSource1.Update()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely follow what's going on here, and I don't have enough reputation to ask in a comment. Where is your save button? I'm guessing it's outside the repeater. Are you trying to save all the companies that appear in your repeater, or is there only one company anyway? What are you trying to get back out of the repeater? Just the company name that's in the textbox? A few more details may provide the help you're looking for.

Also, it might be helpful to add an `OnUpdating` event to your `ObjectDataSource` and handle that in your code behind.

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server"
SelectMethod="GetData" TypeName="WebApplication1.CompanyObject"
UpdateMethod="UpdateCompany" DataObjectTypeName="CompanyObject" 
OnUpdating="Company_Updating"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

And then your code behind:

```
Private Sub Company_Updating(ByVal s As Object, ByVal e As ObjectDataSourceMethodEventArgs)
    ' use e.InputParameters here to pass in the values you need
End Sub
```

You can see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasourcemethodeventargs.inputparameters.aspx) for an example of how to use `InputParameters`.

**Update**

To answer your question, you should be able to use the following to get the value out of the textbox in the repeater:

```
Protected Sub Company_Updating(ByVal s As Object, ByVal e As ObjectDataSourceMethodEventArgs)
    If (Repeater1.Items.Count > 0) Then
        e.InputParameters.Add("CompanyName", CType(Repeater1.Items(0).FindControl("txtCompany"), TextBox).Text
    End If
End Sub
```

But I think a repeater is unnecessary for what you're trying to do here. A repeater is generally used to show a collection of items. If your goal is to simply show one company, couldn't you set the `Text` property of the `TextBox` control in your code behind?

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal s As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If (Not Page.IsPostBack) Then
        txtCompany.Text = yourCompanyObject.Name
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: My save button is outside the repeater.  Only one company appears in the repeater.  What I would like to get back from the repeater is an object with all the modified fields in it.  I will try adding the OnUpdating event and let you know.

Comment: Take a look at my update and let me know if that answers your question.

Comment: I am looking at using a data repeater so that I can data bind to an object data source in both directions.  My goal here is to remove all the left/right code (textbox1.text=value/value=textbox1.text)

Comment: I don't think it's possible to get out of using value=textbox1.text with a repeater.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with a Repeater control:  it doesn't keep a copy of the objects to which it was bound.  It doesn't do two-way binding.

But other controls do.  Check out the [FormView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227970%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s019wc0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), and [DetailsView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3w1w7t4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  For a full treatment of the subject, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228214%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

**This is not possible with the approach you are following.**

We can for sure develop a custom Post Back to achieve the desired output.